# Can't figure out making an Array based off of a Class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

What I'm trying to do is create an array from a Class that holds a list of information.

What I've tried so far is this - First, create the Class:

```
Public Class PowerArray
    Public Name As String
    Public Action As String
    Public Cost As Integer
    Public Pool1 As String
    Public Pool2 As String
    Public Range As String
    Public Duration As String
    Public Tags As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Public Desc As String
End Class
```

Then, define a new object that uses PowerArray as type, contained in a Public Class so it can be called in any sub:

```
Public Class GVar
    Public Shared CharPowers(100) As PowerArray
    Public Shared PCount As Integer = 0
End Class
```

But when I try to write to that object, it keeps throwing a Null Reference Exception.

Example:

Trying to write an entry to CharPowers(GVar.Pcount) (where PCount is currently 0, and "txt.PowerName.Text" is any string):

```
GVar.CharPowers(GVar.PCount).Name = txtPowerName.Text
```

...throws the exception. This happens no matter which value I try to write to.

I haven't had any major hangups going this route when defining a new object inside a sub using that type (not as an array, but just a simple object), so I'm guessing it's the object being an array that's throwing a fit. I just can't figure out how or why. It clearly exists, it's defined on startup.

Comment: fwiw, you should pretty much **NEVER** use `ArrayList`. It was created pre-.Net 2.0 generics, and lives on today exclusively for backwards compatibility and some powershell support, but _has no place at all in new code_. Even if you really don't know what you'll use the collection for, you should still tend to prefer `List(Of Object)`.

Comment: Why ate all the members of PowerArray fields rather than Properites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array in `GVar` is an array of elements typed as `PowerArray` with a value of `Nothing`. You must create an instance of `PowerArray` and assign it to an element is the array before you can set a field of a `PowerArray` object.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PA As New PowerArray
    GVar.CharPowers(GVar.PCount) = PA
    GVar.CharPowers(GVar.PCount).Name = TextBox1.Text
    MessageBox.Show(GVar.CharPowers(GVar.PCount).Name)
End Sub
```

Are you planning on incrementing `PCount`? You would not need to keep track of where you are in the array if you used `List(Of PowerArray)`.

**EDIT**

```
Public Class PowerArray
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Action As String
    Public Property Cost As Integer
    Public Property Pool1 As String
    Public Property Pool2 As String
    Public Property Range As String
    Public Property Duration As String
    Public Property Tags As New List(Of Object)
    Public Property Desc As String
End Class

Public Class GVar
    Public Shared Property CharPowers As New List(Of PowerArray)
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PA As New PowerArray
    PA.Name = TextBox1.Text
    GVar.CharPowers.Add(PA)
    For Each item As PowerArray In GVar.CharPowers
        MessageBox.Show(item.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I was just thinking something similar, and started poking around List. Ran into a new problem with it, though - can't figure out how to Add or Remove items from specific variables in a List object of PowerArray. Example:

set a new oject - Public Shared ChrTester As New List(Of PowerArray) - 

then try to add an entry to a specific value in it:

GVar.ChrTester.Add(GVar.ChrTester.Name "steve") - I'm definitely missing something in how List works, but it's very new to me still.

Comment: See my edit to my answer. I fixed up the classes a bit and demoed how to add and retrieve a property.

Comment: Very nice! Would I be right in assuming multiple Adds (PA.Name = x, PA.Cost = x etc), then doing GVar.CharPowers.Add(PA) would add all the values assigned to PA?

Comment: Couldn't edit the previous comment, but: answered my own question, yes it does! Loading from the List is also MUCH easier with this setup, thank you for explaining Lists. This thing is life-changing

Comment: @ecit I agree. Arrays are in the rear view mirror. If I need an array, I can always call `ToArray` on a `List(Of T)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I tripped over an answer. In particular:

```
Public Class GVar
    Public Shared CharPowers(100) As PowerArray
    Public Shared PCount As Integer = 0
    Shared Sub New()
        For i = 0 To CharPowers.GetUpperBound(0)
            CharPowers(i) = New PowerArray
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to initialize the array GVar.CharPowers first, then use it. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

GVar.CharPowers = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(PowerArray), 19)

Comment: @Edward the 19 in your comment should be 100?

Comment: @djv the 19 is the array size. It seems the topic starter should use the Dictionary (Of <key_type>, PowerArray)